# Windows 10 Event Viewer does not show W3SVC

Tags: windows

As a developer I was expecting to be able to find the stopping and starting of the W3SVC in the application Log in the event viewer but it's not there.

There is also a custom view folder named ServerRoles and init is a Web Server log that is also empty.

I'm speculating there must be a setting to tell W3SVC to write to event viewer.....?

Google has produced numerous hits on viewing web site logs in the event viewer but I must be using the wrong search terms as I can't find anything on why the world wide web service stop and start events aren't showing up.

I've checked Application, System, Security, Setup...in other words I've looked everywhere I can think of

Comment: Services starting and stopping are in the SYSTEM log.

Comment: @Appleoddity..Updated OP. Not there either.